# How to change bootstrap-table row background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

If the result is "good", I want the entire row to turn green. But it does not change anything.

https://jsfiddle.net/Tonato_/tnw3j5p2/7/

Here is the code.

I do not realize at all what is the problem. I think I did it all correctly.

```js
function rowStyle(row, index) {
  const obj = {};
  var classes = ['active', 'success', 'info', 'warning', 'danger'];
  if (Object.keys(row).map(key => row[key]).some(value => String(value).includes('BAD'))) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {
      classes: 'danger'
    });
  }
  if (Object.keys(row).map(key => row[key]).some(value => String(value).includes('GOOD'))) {
    return Object.assign({}, obj, {
      classes: 'success'
    });
  }
  return obj;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark thead-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 8%" class="text-center">Number</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 61%" class="text-center">Present</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10%" class="text-center">Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">01</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title01</td>
    <td>$present01</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">02</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title02</td>
    <td>$present02</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">BAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">03</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title03</td>
    <td>$present03</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: in your fiddle I can't see when you run `rowStyle(row, index)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just update your code with few `jQuery` changes. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.table tr td').each(function(i, v){
    if(v.textContent === 'GOOD') {
      $(v.parentElement).addClass('table-success');
    } else if(v.textContent === 'BAD') {
      $(v.parentElement).addClass('table-danger');
    }
  })  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark thead-inverse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 8%" class="text-center">Number</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 61%" class="text-center">Present</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10%" class="text-center">Result</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">01</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title01</td>
    <td>$present01</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">02</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title02</td>
    <td>$present02</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">BAD</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">03</td>
    <td class="text-center">$title03</td>
    <td>$present03</td>
    <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I made this error after modifying and executing it in Bash script. "v.parentElement: command not found" Bash script also contains Html code.

Comment: can you share the link? Thanks

Comment: I think it should be converted to JavaScript. But I do not know how to convert.

Comment: You need to add my jQuery script in `$(document).ready` method. I also update the above code snippet. Thanks

Comment: @leej0978 if the issue still appeared, please inform me. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. However, the error still appears. 
The following error appears on the terminal.
 :( 


_document: command not found_
_.table tr td: command not found_
_v.parentElement: command not found_

Comment: @leej0978 I just create fiddle with above script with no console error. Please review it. Thanks 
https://jsfiddle.net/creative_sid5/txqhp7os/

Comment: However, the error still appears. I think it should be converted jquery to JavaScript. But I do not know how to convert.

Comment: Error appeared on fiddle or any other link?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it by using simple jQuery code, Run the snippet below

```js
$('table tr').each(function() {
    if($(this).find('td:last-child').html() === 'GOOD'){
        $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
    }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark thead-inverse">
 <thead>
 <tr>
  <th scope="col" style="width: 8%" class="text-center">Number</th>
  <th scope="col" style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Name</th>
  <th scope="col" style="width: 61%" class="text-center">Present</th>
  <th scope="col" style="width: 10%" class="text-center">Result</th>
 </tr>
 </thead>
 <tr>
  <td class="text-center">01</td>
  <td class="text-center">$title01</td>
  <td>$present01</td>
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="text-center">02</td>
  <td class="text-center">$title02</td>
  <td>$present02</td>
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">BAD</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="text-center">03</td>
  <td class="text-center">$title03</td>
  <td>$present03</td>
  <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
 </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First add an id to the table, and then wrap the tr with `<tbody>`.

```
<table id='my-table' data-row-style="rowStyle" class="table table-bordered table-hover thead-dark thead-inverse">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 8%" class="text-center">Number</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 20%" class="text-center">Name</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 61%" class="text-center">Present</th>
      <th scope="col" style="width: 10%" class="text-center">Result</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
      <td class="text-center">01</td>
      <td class="text-center">$title01</td>
      <td>$present01</td>
      <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">02</td>
      <td class="text-center">$title02</td>
      <td>$present02</td>
      <td scope="row" class="text-center">BAD</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">03</td>
      <td class="text-center">$title03</td>
      <td>$present03</td>
      <td scope="row" class="text-center">GOOD</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Then by jQuery use can loop through each tr of tbody in your table. Then based on your result, add css to that row.

```
$('#my-table tbody tr').each(function(i, item){
  var result = $(item).find('td').last().text();
  if(result === 'GOOD') $(item).css('background-color', 'green');
  else $(item).css('background-color', 'red');
})
```